# ajax call and route issues in Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I'm a begginer with Angular, I've followed [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm) tutorial for Single Page Application, importing the templates from different PHP file and using Resource and Route modules, the next code is my js file:

```
(function(){
    var app         = angular.module('empresa', ['empresa.services', 'ngRoute']), 
        services    = angular.module('empresa.services',['ngResource']);

    services.factory('Empresa', ['$resource', function($resource){
        return $resource('empresa', {}, {
            get: {method: 'GET', url: 'empresa/getAll'},
            show: {method: 'GET', url: 'empresa/get/:id' },
            save: {method: 'POST'}
        });
    }]);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
        when('/empresa', {
            templateUrl: 'empresa.htm',
            controller: 'empresa'
        }).otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'empresaindex.htm',
            controller: 'empresa'
        });
    }]);            

    app.controller('empresa', ['$scope', 'Empresa', function($scope, Empresa){

        Empresa.get(function(data){
            $scope.empresas = data.items;
        });

    }]);

})()
```

this is my index.php:

```
<div id="info" ng-app="empresa">    
    <div>
        <?php include('usersmanagement/usertemplates.php'); ?>
        <h2>Administración de Usuarios</h2>
        <div class="row" ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and these ones are my usertemplates.php:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="empresa.htm">
    <h1>Una empresa</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="empresaindex.htm">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nit</th> 
                <th>Razón Social o Nombre</th>
                <th>Mas Detalles</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="empresa in empresas">
                <td>{{ empresa.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ empresa.documento }}</td> 
                <td>{{ empresa.razon_social }}</td>
                <td><a href="#/empresa">Mas Detalles</a></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

I have 2 issues:

- Ajax call is doing three times.
- when I click to the link empresa always to redirect me to the otherwise template, even If I write #empresa at the end of the URL.

The Angular version is 1.5.3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK you don't need the hashtag `#` in your href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really sure what is wrong, but I almost used same code as you do and get no problem to switch state.

```js
 var app = angular.module('empresa', ['empresa.services', 'ngRoute']),
   services = angular.module('empresa.services', ['ngResource']);

 app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
   when('/empresa', {
     templateUrl: 'empresa.htm',
     controller: 'empresa'
   }).otherwise({
     templateUrl: 'empresaindex.htm',
     controller: 'empresa'
   });
 });

 app.controller('empresa', ['$scope',
   function($scope) {

   }
 ]);
```

```html
<body ng-app="empresa">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>


  <script type="text/ng-template" id="empresa.htm">
    <h1>Una empresa</h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="empresaindex.htm">
    <h1>Una empresaindex</h1>
    <a href="#/empresa">Mas Detalles</a>
  </script>

  <div>
    <a href="#/empresa">Mas Detalles</a>
    <a href="#/asdfadsf">Otherwise</a>
    <h2>Administración de Usuarios</h2>
    <div class="row" ng-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if my code was well, but I found the problem it was other script, Thanks!!

Comment: try copy the exact code I wrote and see if it works or not, if it works, there must be something wrong there which is not so obvious

Comment: I copied your code in my project and worked, so I started to check the other imports in the file.php and I found the problem